# Meteor collection always returns undefined on client

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

Im new to meteor and have been trying to learn the framework via the discover meteor book. Im having a few issue understanding what exactly is going on in my application (found here https://github.com/Themitchell/Sound-wav.es).

Essentially, my understanding is that on my server side I allow publications for certain collections which take arguments from my client side subscribe calls. For this part on my server i have this in my server/publications.js file:

```
Meteor.publish('studios', function (options) {
    return Studios.find({
        userId: this.userId
    }, options);
});

Meteor.publish('studio', function (id) {
    return id && Studios.find({
        userId: this.userId,
        _id: id
    });
});
```

Next we would need a controller to handle the routing and deal with waiting for any subscriptions required, then, once the subscriptions are ready (hence the waitOn) go and render the template providing the data function as a reactive data source for the templates.

So I then set up my 2 routes for indexing studios and showing one studio using iron router and 'Controllers' as follows:

```
StudiosIndexController = RouteController.extend({
    template: 'studiosIndex',
    increment: 20,
    limit: function () {
        return parseInt(this.params.studiosLimit) || this.increment;
    },
    findOptions: function () {
        return {
            sort: this.sort,
            limit: this.limit()
        };
    },
    waitOn: function () {
        return Meteor.subscribe('studios', this.findOptions());
    },
    studios: function () {
        return Studios.find({}, this.findOptions());
    },
    data: function () {
        return {
            studios: this.studios()
        };
    }
});

ShowStudioController = RouteController.extend({
    template: 'showStudio',
    waitOn: function () {
        return Meteor.subscribe('studio', this.params._id);
    },
    studio: function () {
        return Studios.findOne(this.params._id);
    },
    data: function () {
        return {
            studio: this.studio()
        };
    }
});

Router.map(function () {
    this.route('studiosIndex', {
        path: '/',
        controller: StudiosIndexController
    });

    this.route('showStudio', {
        path: '/studios/:_id',
        controller: ShowStudioController
    });
});
```

Now this is great and works fine when displaying my index page. I get a list of collections which is reactive and the as i introduce new studios to the collection i see them get created on the server and on the client respectively. However in my show view when the view is rendered the data always seems to be empty. On dropping into my show controller's data function with a debugger I tried querying the Studios and this always returns undefined even when i try to fetch everything possible. Oddly I know that my publications are logging the correct id for a studio (using console.log). It seems that i get all the correct data up until the routing on the client side. The parameter ids are all correct but a find() call on studios always returns nothing. Am I missing something obvious here.

Its also worth noting i deleted my helpers for 'studios' and 'studio' in views/studios/index.js and views/studios/show.js respectively as my understanding is that this is what im doing with studios and studio in the controller. These helpers are now defined at the controller level and passsed to the reactive 'data' function. IS this correct?

**TL;DR**

With the code above my index action works however my show action fails where the data function always returns undefined and in fact on the show page i cannot get access to any of my studio information (Studios.find({}).count() always returns 0). I'm unsure how the 2 routes differ. Can anyone spot the issue?

**Edit:** Its also worth noting having looked through some of the iron router issues on github i have tried using this.ready(). The first time the route is run i hit data and this is false but then even wrapping my data helpers to wait for this.ready() gets an undefined return value when this.ready() returns true.

**Extra Notes**
Im running meteor 0.8.0 with latest 0.7.0 release of iron router and collection2 with simple schema, just in case you are interested / require this info.

**EDIT: Possible solution**
So having fiddled around it seems like my helpers are the issue. By using the 'studio' section and then calling this.studio() inside my data function this seems to break. If I change the code below:

```
ShowStudioController = RouteController.extend({
    template: 'showStudio',
    waitOn: function () {
        return Meteor.subscribe('studio', this.params._id);
    },
    studio: function () {
        return Studios.findOne(this.params._id);
    },
    data: function () {
        return {
            studio: this.studio()
        };
    }
});
```

to this

```
ShowStudioController = RouteController.extend({
    template: 'showStudio',
    waitOn: function () {
        return Meteor.subscribe('studio', this.params._id);
    },
    data: function () {
        return Studios.findOne(this.params._id);
    }
});
```

My view renders correctly again. Im unsure where i saw this pattern however I had assumed the function assigned to 'studio' was essentially the same as doing

```
Template.showStudio.helpers({
    studio: function () {
        return Studios.findOne(this.params._id)
    }
});
```

but it seems not!

Comment: Which version of `iron-router` you are using?

Comment: Ah in before the edit. 0.8.0 meteor with 0.7.0 iron-router

Comment: Would you please try doing two things: (1) add `Router.onBeforeAction('loading')` and a login template to your Router configuration (2) try changing the `waitOn` hook to `onBeforeAction`. You don't really need to wait for your subscriptions but if you have to, do it inside `onBeforeAction` by calling `this.subscribe(...).wait()`.

Comment: Hmmmm no change it would seem. I was actually already adding the Router.onBeforeAction('loading') in my router file. Changing my subscriptions though still has the same result both with and without using this.ready() inside the data function

Comment: I just edited the post in regards to what seems to have solved the issue for me. Again im unsure where i grabbed the pattern i was using. Possibly some old iron router examples as i realise there are some significant changes in how iron-router works with blaze